# SKStoreViewController Sandbox issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, in-app-purchase, storekit

```
int productID = xxx;
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:productID]};

    [self.storeViewController loadProductWithParameters:parameters
                                        completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
                                            if (result)
                                            {
                                                [self presentViewController:self.storeViewController animated:YES completion:^{

                                                }];
                                            }
                                        }];
```

I also created test account on itunes connect and earlier I was able to install this application through test account, but now each time or on other devices I got error. Screenshot attached[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alert view shows that your test was successful. Apple does not let you actually install it since it wants to avoid making app purchases in sandbox mode.